# What can this $\int_{0}^{t} (\pi(x)-Li(x)) dx$ tell us about primes distribution?

Tags: prime-numbers, integration, prime-number-theorem, polylogarithms

Many papers I have read which are related to primes distribution only it  discussed sign and refinement Bounds of $\pi(x)-Li (x)$ with $\pi(x)$ is a prime counting function and $Li (x)$ is the logarithm integral $x$ , I computed $\int_{0}^{1} (\pi(x)-Li (x)) $ I [have got](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%28%28Pi%28x%29-li%28x%29%29%29%2C+x%3D0+to+1) $\log 2$, this result attracted my attention to the behavior of $\int_{0}^{t} (\pi(x)-Li (x))dx $ , such that i can't juge weither it is divergent or convergent integral , But my question here is:

> **Question**: What can this $\int_{0}^{t} ( \pi(x)-Li (x)) $ tell us about primes distribution ?

Comment: Note that you merely computed the integral of $\operatorname{Li}(x)$, as $\pi(x)=0$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Up to the sign.

Comment: Apart from that, I doubt that the integral converges, as Littlewood proved the difference $\pi(x)-Li(x)$ changes sign infinitely often. I think he also proved this difference is not bounded.

Comment: What do you mean you can't tell whether the integral $\int_0^t(\pi(x)-\text{li}(x))\,dx$ converges or diverges? Do you really mean whether $\underset{t\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\int_0^t(\pi(x)-\text{li}(x))\,dx\right)$ converges or diverges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral does not converge. See https://academic.oup.com/blms/article-abstract/31/4/424/277640?redirectedFrom=fulltext.

On the other hand, a proof that this integral is less than $K.t^{\alpha}$ almost everywhere (i.e. on a set of the form $(t_{0},\infty)\setminus J$ where $J$ has Lebesgue measure $0$) for some $\alpha<2$ and an absolute constant $K$ would imply that there exists some $1/2\leq\sigma_{0}<1$ such that $\zeta$ does not vanish in the right half plane $\Re(s)>\sigma_{0}$, which quantifies the "randomness" of the distribution of the primes: the less $\sigma_{0}$, the less random this distribution.